# Spanish phrase meaning 'thrive without gods'

Tags: traducción, solicitud-de-término, saludos

Blame it on all the cowboy movies, but I've always enjoyed the sound of 'adios' as a farewell. I don't want to be burdened by the superstitious baggage that 'adios' brings with it. Can someone invent a short, sharp, euphonic Spanish protologism, neologism or nonce word/phrase that means 'thrive without gods'?

Comment: Thinly veiled attempt to disrespect the beliefs of others by cleverly disguising as a question

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Well, to begin it should be made clear that, while *adiós* indeed comes from the phrase *a Dios os encomiendo* (*I entrust you to God*), like the phrase *ojalá* (from لو شاء الله meaning *if God wills <sub>(it)</sub>*), today it no longer is seen to have any religious significance.  My atheist friends who are very particular about language<sup>1</sup> have no problem using it.  In that regards, it's much like using *good-bye* in English.

A simple one that you can use, but that I don't know it has much usage outside of Spain, is *agur* which derives from Euskera (Basque), but even that comes originally from Latin *[augurium](http://www.perseus.tufts.edu/hopper/morph?l=augurium&la=latin)* so you aren't really removing yourself from "superstitious baggage".

Other farewells tend to be relatively context-sensitive, but you can often hear things like *que te vaya bien* (*may things go well for you*) which might additionally have other words attached, for example, *que te/os/le/les<sup>2</sup> vaya bien la vida* (*may/I hope life treat you/y'all well*).  But this isn't *per se* a farewell, and can be used in other, non-farewell contexts: if someone has told you in the conversation that they have a big test tomorrow, using it will be interpreted as wishing them well on the test, not generally.  Additionally, you have to consider who you're saying it to and where you are.

Another potential option is *cuídate/cuidate/cuidaos/cuídese/cuidense*<sup>3</sup> which means *take care (of yourself/y'all's selves)*.  But it too has the problem of multiple forms depending on who you're talking to and where you are.

The last group of farewells, which are probably the most common after *adiós* generally begin with *hasta* (*until*).  For example, *hasta mañana* (lit. *until tomorrow*, that is, *see you tomorrow*) or *hasta luego* (*until later*).  If you won't ever see them again, you can use the phrase *hasta nunca* (*until never*, that is, *hope to never see you again*), but that has a very negative feel and certainly doesn't wish them well.  You substitute *te/os/lo/la/le/los/las/les veo* instead of *hasta* (lit. *I <sub>(will)</sub> see you/y'all*), but it has so many different potential words based on where and who you're speaking to, if you're not actually a Spanish-speaker it might be best to avoid it.<sup>4</sup>

There is one final option that you could potentially use.  It is short, and unrelated to deities.  It is *vale* which derives the identical Latin phrase meaning *stay<sub>(sing.)</sub> well*.  The problem (and honestly why it didn't come to me on the initial writing of this answer), is that in a number of countries —especially Spain— *vale* is indeed used as an interjection, but one meaning closer to the English word *okay*.  When it is used in Modern Spanish with the meaning of *farewell*, it tends to be in a very different context: funerals.  For example, *vale, mi amigo* would mean *farewell (forever), my friend*, and wouldn't be super appropriate in more, shall we say, cheery circumstances.  It also has a number of other meanings, some of which could be confused in context: in the Dominican Republic *vale* can be a rural person, so telling some *vale* could be the same as calling them *redneck* or *countrybumpkin* to their face.

---

<sup>1. By this I mean my friends who are both particular about language and atheists (which are of course unrelated traits).  By particular, I mean having a high tendency to use things like *x* or *@* to neutralize gender, etc.  The ones who are very concerned about the subconscious effects of language.</sup>

<sup>2. te (informal or intermediate formality, singular), os (informal and plural, Spain and Equatorial Guinea only), le (formal and singular), les (formal and plural, Spain and Equatorial Guinea; plural without distinction to formality everywhere else)</sup>

<sup>3. in order we have first the informal (or intermediate formal in countries with three-way distinctions like Chile), informal singular (for countries with vos like Argentina), informal plural (for Spain and Equatorial Guinea; very formal if used in singular), formal singular, and plural (formal in Spain and Equatorial Guinea, no distinction elsewhere).</sup>

<sup>4. Suffice it to say, we have informal and intermediate formality forms (*te*, singular, *os* plural in Spain and Equatorial Guinea), formal forms in non-leísta or leísta de cortesía zones (*lo* singular masculine, *la* singular feminine, *los* masculine plural, *las* feminine plural) formal forms in leísta de cortesía zones (*le* singular without gender distinction, *les* plural without gender distinction), or formal forms in standard leísta zones (*le* for masculine singular, *la* for femoinine singular, *les* for masculine plural, *las* for feminine plural)</sup>

Comment: Una respuesta muy completa y didáctica, como siempre. Genial el formato.

Comment: Since guifa's answer indicates that there is no extant, succinct Spanish expression for 'thrive without gods', perhaps my question should be,'What new, or nonce expression in Spanish might mean 'thrive without gods'?

Comment: Let's not forget that "Adios" can also be a brief hello-type greeting in passing.  // One can take one's leave by saying "Buen día," "Que tenga buen día" (Que tenga un buen resto del día.)  In the evening, "Buenas noches.  // In certain contexts, "¡Suerte!" can be an effective way of sending someone on his way (~French "Courage!").  Also "¡Adelante!" (Onward and upward!).

Comment: @Diego I disagree this is off topic.  Also, I remembered a word that does exist (if hardly ever used today with that meaning, and have edited my answer)

Comment: @guifa, it does not show previous research effort to me. While the question mentions "adiós" and the problems with it, I can't believe that other farewell forms could not be easily found (Schwarzenegger made _"Hasta la vista"_ quite popular and "Nos vemos" would be a direct translation of "See you"). If the OP wants Spanish for "thrive with gods" some attempt to translate should be made. Nevertheless, you can flag and/or vote the question for reopening. Actually, given your high-quality answer I would retitle the question as "How can I wish farewell to someone in Spanish" and VTR

Comment: @Diego actually, there is no reopen vote available

Comment: @guifa, OK, reopened, but then I'm closing [Spanish nonce words](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/q/20588/5481) as duplicate. While I understand both are the same, the phrasing of this one, to me, could be seen as off-topic or lacking effort, while the other one is not. I could answer this question in a couple ways (ej: "Que todo vaya bien") that would not address the other question.

Comment: My edited question is informed by @guifa's answer and based on the assumption that Spanish is alive to protologisms, neologisms and nonce words. As an Australian English-speaker (or butcherer) I could cobble together a pidgin Spanish nonce expression, but I would hope that Spanish speakers with some invention and flair could  do it better. Nos vemos.

Comment: During my research I toyed with 'prospera sin dioses', but the inclusion of 'sin' seemed to be taking me around in circles.

Comment: @AreelXocha so you *did* some research but did not show that in your question. I recommend you to visit the [tour] and [help] sections to learn more about the philosophy of the site. Also, I wish you had edited this question with what you have in the "nonce words" question, which I believe is a better phrasing for the question, instead of creating a duplicate. Finally, feel welcome to the community. Please don't hesitate to ask for advice if you have trouble understanding functionality or _best practices_.  Vale.