# Where does "Hola" come from? / ¿De dónde viene "Hola"?

Tags: etimología, saludos

The word "**Hola**" is probably the most used salutation in the Spanish language.
Some say it comes from Latin, others that it is an Arabic word, others claim English roots... (I'm sure details will be posted in the answers).

But really, where does "**Hola**" come from?

---

La palabra "**Hola**" es probablemente el saludo más usado en lengua española.
Algunos dicen que viene del latín, otros que es una palabra árabe, otros que tiene raíces inglesas... (estoy seguro de que las respuestas darán más detalles).

Pero en serio, ¿de dónde viene la palabra "**Hola**"?

Comment: Por si a alguien le interesa, [aquí tenemos la etimología de _"Adiós"_](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/a/20581/5481).

Comment: Al parecer no se sabe su origen, aparte de las hipótesis antes mencionadas también he escuchado que puede venir de la exclamación de sorpresa inglesa "hullo". La respuesta correcta es de momento "no sabemos".

Comment: Si buscar el origen de las palabras fuera mi profesion o mi pasatiempo entonces buscaría y anotaría el.año mas antiguo usado en el language escrito: notas, cartas, libros, etc. Siempre esperando que otra persona demuestre una fecha aun mas antigua. Por ejemplo
19xx Don Quijote
15xx Don "Hola"

Answer (score 7, accepted):

"Hola" parece venir de voces expresivas para infundir aliento o apresurar el paso, al igual que la palabra "hala" o la voz francesa *holá* y el *hallo* inglés.

De acuerdo a [Wikipedia](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hola_(saludo)):

> Según el DRAE la palabra **hola** es una voz expresiva que podría estar relacionada con el inglés *hello* y el alemán *hallo*.​ Corominas la considera también una voz de creación expresiva, y la relaciona además con el español **hala**.​ La primera referencia de la palabra **hola** que se tiene constancia en español data de 1552.
>
> Si se acepta la relación del español **hola** con la palabra inglesa *hello*, variación decimonónica a su vez de *hallo* o *hollo*, se puede considerar que la palabra española comparta la etimología que proporciona el *Oxford English Dictionary Online*, que la relaciona con el antiguo alto alemán «*halâ*, *holâ*, imperativo enfático de *halôn*, *holôn* **‘traer, alcanzar’, utilizada especialmente para saludar a un barquero»**.​ El mismo diccionario la relaciona también con **el francés *holà* (literalmente «¡eh, ahí!», de *là*, «ahí»)**

De acuerdo a [Etimologías de Chile](http://etimologias.dechile.net/?hola) podría venir del griego οὖλε  (que significa "salve", una expresión que ya aparece en *La Odisea* de Homero), aunque la propia web de Etimologías de Chile reconoce que la RAE relaciona *hola* con el inglés *hello*, que a su vez vendría de *hallo*, presente desde mediados del siglo XVI.

El [Wiktionario](https://es.wiktionary.org/wiki/hola), alude a una "etimología incierta" y menciona una hipótesis **desacreditada** que relacionaría "hola" con un origen árabe en والله (*wallāh*, "por dios"). Otras teorías sugieren que es una especie de [*acrónimo ibérico* para significar "todo"](http://www.academia.edu/3112247/El_origen_de_la_palabra_HOLA).

Comment: Siendo arabe, la palabra arabe mas cercana a "hola" es "Ahlan", y esa usamos en arabe exactamente como ustedes usan "hola" en espanol, asi como un saludo casual. "Ahlan" tambien tiene otra forma usada mas en Libano, que es "Hala".

Answer (score 10):

Por dejar aquí constancia de lo que opinaba la RAE en el siglo XVIII (Diccionario de Autoridades):

> HOLA. interj. Modo vulgar de hablar usado para llamar a otro que es inferior. Latín *Heus*, que es de donde viene.

Resulta curioso que por entonces se considerara una forma vulgar de saludar, por lo que podría ser utilizado hasta como insulto contra la persona adecuada. Covarrubias directamente lo describe así:

> HOLA, y hao, está corrompido de *heus*, adverbium vocandi.

Vamos, adverbio para llamar a otras personas. No da muchas más explicaciones, pero insiste en su origen latino. Y por contradecir un poco a Corominas (autor que cita la Wikipedia), veo un caso de "hola" en el CORDE de 1528:

> *A vos, hermano. ¡Hola! ¿Mora aquí una señora que se llama la Loçana?*
>
> Francisco Delicado, "La Lozana Andaluza", 1528 (España).

Comment: Don Quijote usa a veces la palabra *hola* para apelar a Sancho cuando está enfadado con él. Esto es coherente con lo que aparece en el Diccionario de Autoridades.

Answer (score 2):

Estoy Estudiando el inglés antiguo (Old English), que floreció entre los siglos V y X d.C., y he visto que para saludar utilizaban la palabra Ēalās (pronunciado Éalas). 
El inglés antiguo, de origen germánico del Bajo Alemán, tenía inflexiones para indicar la función gramatical de una palabra. Justo cuando 'ēalās' iba delante de un nombre se convertía en 'ēalā', y en mi humilde opinión, muy similar a nuestro 'hola' y al portugués 'olá'. Por ejemplo: Ēalā freond --》 Hello friend (en el inglés actual).

Comment: La única referencia que encuentro a la expresión es en los evangelios de Wessex (1175): _Ða cwæð se hælend to hym. **Eala freond** to hwam be-come þu. Ða geneahlacten hyo & þanne hælend ge-namen._ Inglés actual: _And Jesus said unto him, Friend, do that for which thou art come. Then they came and laid hands on Jesus, and took him._

Comment: @walen y Cinta: lo he [preguntado en ELU](https://english.stackexchange.com/q/507495/280768) para obtener una segunda opinión. La teoría suena interesante pero tengo dudas que considero razonables, a ver si allí nos pueden aclarar esto. Cinta, como ha dicho walen, si tienes fuentes que podamos consultar, añádelas a la respuesta y así tendremos algo con más sustancia.